# Conditional aggregation in scala based on data type

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do you aggregate dynamically in scala spark based on data types?

For example:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(when  DOUBLE type)
, APPEND(when STRING), MAX(when BOOLEAN) 
from tbl  
GROUP BY ID
```

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5OyN.png)

Comment: it will be good if you give an example with sample data and code. i dont think with simple sql statement  some one can give an answer. please eloborate with code. this can be achived with scala spark data frame api rather sql. means you have to do it programatic way with scala dataframe api based on data type

Comment: you are right, I am thinking programatic as well. Here are some sample data:

Comment: Hello @touelv ! Can you please read the following https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and review your question according to these guidelines ? Thanks !

Comment: Don't ever post images for sample data. And also if the answer helped you don't forget to accept it.

Comment: Understood, it is my first post, I am learning how to navigate the site

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by getting the runtime schema matching on the datatype, example :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import spark.implicits._

val df =Seq(
  (1, 1.0, true, "a"),
  (1, 2.0, false, "b")
).toDF("id","d","b","s")

val dataTypes: Map[String, DataType] = df.schema.map(sf => (sf.name,sf.dataType)).toMap

def genericAgg(c:String) = {
  dataTypes(c) match {
    case DoubleType => sum(col(c))
    case StringType => concat_ws(",",collect_list(col(c))) // "append"
    case BooleanType => max(col(c))
  }
}

val aggExprs: Seq[Column] = df.columns.filterNot(_=="id") // use all
    .map(c => genericAgg(c))

df
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(
    aggExprs.head,aggExprs.tail:_*
  )
  .show()
```

gives

```
+---+------+------+-----------------------------+
| id|sum(d)|max(b)|concat_ws(,, collect_list(s))|
+---+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1|   3.0|  true|                          a,b|
+---+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: One more thing, I get the error below ""<console>:74: error: not found: type Column
       val aggExprs: Seq[Columns] = output.columns.filterNot(_=="id")// use all""